# Animated button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use this jQuery function on an animated button is not really working, can I get help with that? Below are the codes

HTML

```
<button class="btn-rounded">Button</butto>
```

CSS

```
.btn-rounded{
    color: black;
    opacidity:.7;
    border-radius:150px;
    background-color:#FFF067;
}
```

JS

```
$("#img").addClass("animated bounce");
```

Comment: Your jquery references `#img` which doesn't exist, and just calls addClass. What animation are you trying to achieve? Please be as specific as you can. Oh and you misspelled `opacity`

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please tell us what you expect.

Comment: The end tag for the button should be `</button>`, not `</butto>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your js is not targeting the button at all, but rather an element `#img`. Besides it simply adds the classes to the element immediately on page load, irregardless of action.

To trigger the button animation on click, you'll need to create an event handler to apply the classes to the button when clicked.

```
$('button.btn-rounded').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just skip the jQuery and use plain ol' vanilla CSS.

```
.btn-rounded {
  color: black;
  opacity:.7;
  border-radius:150px;
  background-color:#FFF067;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(0.5, -2.5, 0.5, 3.5);
}

.btn-rounded:hover {
  transform: translateY(-25%);
}
```

Now, if you hover over it this bad boy will bounce for ya. Don't forget to fix the opacity typo in your CSS and the the button typo in you HTML.